# Zipping Things Using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, zip, gnustep

I'm learning Objective-C using GNUstep(because I use Linux). I was thinking in create a simple zipper application only to practice, but how where i can find a tutorial to build it? and which is the common library used to this things in Objective-C? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could reference the accepted answer to ["How can I create a zip file by using Objective-C?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c), or
2. Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can freely link to whatever C zip library is convenient for you (such as [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)), or
3. You can call out to the zip and unzip shell utilities available on your Linux system and interact with them using pipes or temporary locations for the files.

Answer (score 3):

If your want to create an application that mimics gzip probably the best library to use is [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)

although this is a purely c implementation.  Also see here: [objective-c file compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c)