# How to make a .zip file in iphone using objective C?

Tags: iphone

I want to create a .zip file using Objective-C.

Is there is any method for this or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the zlib library with iPhone SDK.

This discussion provide more details http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7367520

Answer (score 1):

check out for [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) which is an Objective-C class to compress or uncompress zip files, which is base on open source code "MiniZip".

It can be used for iPhone application development, and cocoa on Mac OSX as well.