# How can I create a Zip archive file in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, zip, gzip, archive, archive-file

I have attempted to find a way to create a zip archive (or GZip archive) in Objective-C, but my knowledge of the language is still lacking.

I see a way to compress an existing data structure in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c), but it does not seem to answer the question of how to make an archive.

To be explicitly clear:  by archive I mean the equivalent of a zip file or GZip file that contains many different files internally, and are archived and then compressed for transfer or usage as a single entity.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you linked to - see the 2nd answer that mentions using Info-Zip.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c

Comment: So, I do not see how this is a duplicate of that - none of those responses seem to be explaining how to ARCHIVE the files, simply how to compress already created data streams.  What I am attempting to determine is how to also archive elements/files inside those data streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a zip command from a command line instead of doing the tar archive.