# create zip archive using NSTask containing a first level folder with the files

Tags: cocoa, zip, nstask

my method works for zipping files from a temporary directory previously created and populated:

```
NSURL *destURL = self.archiveDestURL;
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:[srcURL path]]; 
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/zip"];
NSArray *argsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-r", @"-q", [destURL path], @".", @"-i", @"*", nil];
[task setArguments:argsArray];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

but what i'd like to have when unzipped, is a folder with the files.
sure i can make a folder in the tempDir and write my files there, but what is the zip argument for having a folder be the top level in the created archive?

i didn't see this in  `man zip` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you.

```
NSTask *unzip = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[unzip setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/unzip"];
[unzip setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-u", @"-d", 
                     destination, zipFile, nil]];

NSPipe *aPipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
[unzip setStandardOutput:aPipe];

[unzip launch];
[unzip waitUntilExit];
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `NSTask`, you could incorporate compress functionality into your code. there are several options.

1. [ZipBrowser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ZipBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple.com
2. adding a category to `NSData`, as in [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UsingZipFilesExamples)
3. a similar question. [How can I create a zip file by using Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c)

Comment: cesar, thanks for your suggestions. my app just needs to make a zip archive if the user chooses that option, not read one. sorry for not being clear about that, so i don't see the need to categorize `NSData` as in the link you've referenced (which also uses `NSTask`), or in ZipBrowser's case, create class files to handle things. i'm looking for the possibility of staying within the built-in library and thought someone might know the correct arguement to hand off to it.

Comment: by 'unzipping' i mean what the user sees when she double-clicks on the zip archive in the finder.