# zlib decompression method with unknown object types

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, zlib, nsstream

I am on a quest to figure out how to decompress some NSData thats been compressed using Zlib. I have recently had some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832172/748343),  I had added the second method into the my class where I need to use it but not the first as I do not need to compress the NSData only decompress.

However I am having trouble with these lines of code

```
z_stream strm;
strm.next_in = (Bytef *)[compressedData bytes];
strm.avail_in = (unsigned int)[compressedData length];
strm.total_out = 0;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
```

I do not know the object types of **z-stream** or **strm** I have tried declaring them in my header as NSStreams but that dose not do anything.

the errors I am getting are as follows

[image: Use of undeclared identifier 'z_stream']

any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't *included* (imported) the header file that defines `z_stream`:

```
#import "zlib.h"
```

Comment: oh man! thanks a bunch!! i have been googling the heck out of this you would have thought it would have known LOL

Also I had zlib imported before i put the code in then took it out then inserted the code.. what an idiot. thank you very much for your answer I will mark it correct once time is up.