# Compress files from mobile and upload it to server?

Tags: android, ios, compression, backup, restore

I have developed an application for backup and restore on IOS and ANDROID!
for backup i am just looping all files and uploading to server directly and to restore, doing the same to retrieve the data's back to phone.

But

1.now i have to compress the files and upload it to server,
2.also decompress it and restore it back to mobile
3.most important this must be done by cross platform method..
    (i.e i have to take a backup from iPhone and restore it to an android phone.)

Is there any way out there related answers or suggestion's are welcome.

thank you

Comment: This question has a link-only answer that may be deleted. It points to [this article](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29) though it appears to be suffering a database outage at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android you can use the java.util.zip (try [Zipping with android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)) to zip your files and upload to the server and on IOS you can use the ZipFile class (look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c) for an example) to do exactly the same. Zip is a standard so it will work both ways.