# unzip source code in Iphone

Tags: iphone

I think I found some discussions on the above topic but nothing very clear. But I would like to know if there is any open source code for unzippping multiple files. I am trying to come up with utility that could download a zip file (with multiple iamges) and extract it in the Iphone .

Answer (score 3):

I recommend my library [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive).

Usage:

```
NSString *path = @"path_to_your_zip_file";
NSString *destination = @"path_to_the_folder_where_you_want_it_unzipped";
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very close to yours, and the answers include links to source code for unzipping files in Cocoa: ["Compression API on the iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone).

Comment: Thanks for the link . It says about using zlib which uses g zip, that is used to compress one file at a time. I need to download the zip file having multiple files and then use them. Can zlib be still be used for it?