# How to unzip a password protected zip file in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, unzip, php-ziparchive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unzip source code in Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208288/unzip-source-code-in-iphone)
>   [Obj-C, zip libary which will zip and unzip, with password protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313571/obj-c-zip-libary-which-will-zip-and-unzip-with-password-protection)

I have a password-protected zip-file that contains a text file. I need to unzip it using a password and save the text file to a string. How to unzip in iOS?

IN KOREAN :

나는 한국 사람입니다. ios를 공부하고 있습니다.

Zipfile을 가지고 있습니다.

Zipfile은 암호를 가지고 있고, Zipfile안에 TxT파일이 있습니다.

암호가 있는 Zipfile의 암축을 해제하고, 그 안에 있는 Txt파일의 내용을 String에 넣고 싶습니다.

ios에서 압축을 해제하려면 어떻게 하나요?

알려주시길 부탁드립니다.

Comment: Hi Teajong, thanks for your question. I can understand the English part of your question ok :)  But the question is a duplicate of another one.  It's a good idea to search the site for existing answers to your question before posting a new one.
Check out the Stackoverflow FAQ for general advice on using the site: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: p.s. you don't need to explain where you're from or that you're studying iOS -- just ask your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into gzip, libz.dylib. that is the library for compression i'm not sure if it supports password protected files but for compressing , decompressing files and strings it works grea, you should look into that