# Unzip NSData without temporary file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, unzip

I've found a couple of libs ([LiteZip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/LiteZip.aspx) and [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)) that allow to unzip files on iPhone. But both of them require an input as a file. Is there a library that allows to directly unzip NSData containing zip-archived data without writing it to temporary file? 

 I've tried to adopt mentioned above libs for that, but with no success so far.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a temporary file? In what form do you want the uncompressed data? Is it some actual zipped data that you have in your NSData?

Comment: I have encrypted zip file. I decrypt it in memory to NSData and then want to unzip it directly.

Comment: I once wrote exactly what you need (with the exception of the encryption support). It was pretty easy and realized in a few hours. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code anymore. So why don't you write one from scratch (with the use of zlib)? The ZIP file is a rather easy file format.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone/234099#234099) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone), I point out the CocoaDev wiki [category on NSData](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory) which adds zip / unzip support to that class.  This would let you do this entirely in memory.

Comment: This category adds gzip/zlib support, not the actual zip format (which by the way couldn't be decompressed to a single NSData object that cannot represent the files/directories structure).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the zip format stores files separately and each stored file is compressed using a compression algorithm (generally it's the DEFLATE algorithm).

If you're only interested in uncompressing data that was compressed using the DEFLATE algorithm you could use this [zlib addition to NSData](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSData%2Bzlib.h) from [Google Toolbox For Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac)
It doesn't need temporary files.

Comment: Since files in zip archives are stored individually compressed, And in their original folder hierarchy, it should be possible to extract an NSData object by simply passing a path (relative to the root of the zip archive), right?