# Unzip a file in ios during a game

Tags: iphone, ios5

We have an ios game and we would like to unzip a zip file while the game is running.
Therefore we need minimal impact on cpu. How should we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your unzipping in the background and on a separate thread.

You have a couple choices in unzipping classes.  There's [ZipZap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap), [ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) and [other stuff found in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727952/unzip-nsdata-without-temporary-file).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a low priority concurrent dispatch queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
  // unzip here
});
```

Michael Dautermann has already listed some of the unzipping choices.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for that low priority too