# How to write multiple files from one NSData object?

Tags: iphone, zip, unzip

I'm writing an iPhone app that includes in-app purchasing. It downloads a zip file, then I unzip the file using the [popular NSData category (zlibDeflate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505499/simplest-way-on-iphone-to-unzip-downloaded-file) which outputs the uncompressed file into an NSData object. The zip file contains multiple files in it which I need to write to the Documents directory. How can I write each file separately from this one NSData object? writeToFile just writes the whole thing to one file.

Thank you and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still haven't fixed this, you could try and use:

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

and read the comments to the documentation here:

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/wiki/PageName

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going this route a few days ago. I originally had trouble compiling the ZipArchive scripts, so I was trying the NSData approach, but then I found this and I was able to compile it: http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/issues/detail?id=4