# iphone: coding a data compression or zipping agent?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, compression, zip, ios

I'm creating a simple service for uploading photographs from an iphone to a web server.

However, before the requests is sent, I want the app to compress the pictures (custom format or otherwise) in the background before sending it.

Any pointers on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Take a look to see if Google's protobufs are available for objective-c

Comment: Modern picture file formats are already compressed. Zipping these usually doesn't lead to any benefit. I just tried on my mac with png and jpeg. The size stayed the same. so in ur case it will lead to extra work on the iOS device and server, but probably won't give u any profit. If u want to zip several files to one, as the server expect one, u should — if possible — consider to change ur server-side programming to except more than one file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compression API on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the NSDataCategory posted to CocoaDev.  It does exactly what you're looking to do.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory

Answer (score 0):

I use ziparchive to unzip content downloaded from a server.  It also has functionality to create zip files on an iOS device and might be what you are looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/