# How to uncompress a gzip file and write that out to an uncompressed file, on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gzip

I've got a file, bigfile.gz, in the bundle of my iPhone app.  At app start, I want to gunzip that file to my Documents directory within my app.  How can I achieve this programmatically?

Basically I want the effect of: `gunzip bigfile.gz`.. obviously a `gunzip` utility is not available in the iOS environment though.

Comment: Take a look: http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

Comment: Turns out there's no reason to do any of this in my case.  The IPA is going to be zipped anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in this post:

[Compression API on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone)

both zlib and bzip2 are available. However, as another answer there points out, if you store the data for the conversations in an `NSData` object, then you can use an `NSData` category that adds gzip and zlib compression / decompression as simple methods. Here's a [useful link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory) for that.

Comment: the link that works is http://web.archive.org/web/20100102154917/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory