# iOS unzip .gz file

Tags: objective-c, ios, gzip, php-ziparchive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to uncompress a gzip file and write that out to an uncompressed file, on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740820/how-to-uncompress-a-gzip-file-and-write-that-out-to-an-uncompressed-file-on-iph)

Im trying to unzip a .gz sqlite file in iOS, but until now I did not found a good library for that.

I tried `SSZipArchive` like that:

```
path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"test.sqlite" ofType:@"gz"];

NSString *documentsDir = (NSString *)[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
destination = documentsDir;
NSError *error;

BOOL success =  [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination overwrite:YES password:nil error: &error];
```

That works for a zipped sqlite database file, but not if I gzip the sqlite database. Then everytime the error "cant open zip file" is returning.

Then I tried this `GZIP` approach from https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP.
I used the code like that:

```
path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"test.sqlite" ofType:@"gz"];

NSString *documentsDir = (NSString *)[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
destination = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];


NSData *gzData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSData *ungzippedData = [gzData gunzippedData];

return [ungzippedData writeToFile:destination atomically:YES];
```

After that I got a file named test.sqlite in my Documents folder, but if I try to open it, it fails because the fail is corrupt.

And my last  try was `ZipArchive` from http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/.
I used it like that:

```
ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
if( [za UnzipOpenFile:path] ){
    BOOL success = [za UnzipFileTo:destination overWrite:YES];
    [za UnzipCloseFile];
    return success;
}
```

But this also cant open the file.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hello Andy,I am facing same issue in my app.have you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is zlib library use can add to your target in linker settings in Xcode.

Here you can find example on how to use zlib. http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html