# Get the compressed response data with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

When I add an "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header field to my NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest requests compressed data from the server and automatically decompresses the response data. Is there a way to prevent this, i.e. obtain the compressed (still gzipped) data?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 0):

That kind of thing is acomplished using NSURLDownload class on Mac OS X. [Apple says](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html):

> iOS Note: The NSURLDownload class is not available in iOS, because
>   downloading directly to the file system is discouraged. Use the
>   NSURLConnection class instead. See “Using NSURLConnection” for more
>   information.

So, you'd want to evaluate your options - and use [some library to zip it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone) back and save it.

Comment: Running on iOS, having the system decompress it and then compress it again myself is probably not the best solution.