# OSError -40 while converting an audio file to Byte array iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays

I am using the following code in iOS to convert an mp3 file to byte array. However, on entering the while loop, it gives err = -40  (OSError = -40) . Can anyone please help. Or kindly let me know how i can convert an mp3/wav file to bytearray. Reference - [How to convert WAV/CAF file's sample data to byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996236/how-to-convert-wav-caf-files-sample-data-to-byte-array)

```
 NSString *urlHere = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"r2d2" ofType:@"mp3"];
 CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlHere];


AudioFileID audioFile;
OSStatus err = AudioFileOpenURL(url, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &audioFile);
// get the number of audio data bytes
UInt64 numBytes = 0;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(numBytes);
err = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &dataSize, &numBytes);

unsigned char *audioBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(numBytes);

UInt32 toRead = numBytes;
UInt64 offset = 0;
unsigned char *pBuffer = audioBuffer;
while(true) {
    err = AudioFileReadBytes(audioFile, true, offset, &toRead, &pBuffer);
    if (kAudioFileEndOfFileError == err) {
        // cool, we're at the end of the file
        break;
    } else if (noErr != err) {
        // uh-oh, some error other than eof
        break;
    }
    // advance the next read offset
    offset += toRead;
    // advance the read buffer's pointer
    pBuffer += toRead;
    toRead = numBytes - offset;
    if (0 == toRead) {
        // got to the end of file but no eof err
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This error means "Invalid File Position" for what it's worth.

Comment: Ok... so, is the issue created by CFURLRef ? How else can i possibly use AudioFileOpenURL. Please help.

Comment: Be more specific about when it gives that message.  First iteration of the loop?  Last iteration?  Middle?

Comment: First iteration when err = AudioFileReadBytes(audioFile, true, offset, &toRead, &pBuffer); is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
All you need to do is to remove the `&` sign next to the `pBuffer` variable, since it is already a pointer:

```
err = AudioFileReadBytes(audioFile, true, offset, &toRead, pBuffer);
```