# AVAudioRecorder swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, avaudiorecorder

I had my `AVAudioRecorder` working, but since upgrading to swift 2, I can't seem to figure out how to configure it correctly. I keep getting an error saying the `AVAudioRecorder` initializer cannot be invoked, but the parameters I'm providing look correct to me.

```
var recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue))]


var recordingURL: NSURL? = nil
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!


func directoryURL() -> NSURL? {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
    return soundURL 
}

@IBAction func recordPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch _ {
    }

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }

    var error: NSError?

    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: recordingURL, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)

    if let e = error {

        print(e.localizedDescription, terminator: "")
    }
    else
    {
        audioRecorder.record()
        self.stopButton.enabled = true
        self.playButton.enabled = false
        self.recordButton.enabled = false

    }


}
```

Comment: `recordingURL` vs. `directoryURL`? You are returning the name of the file in `directoryURL()`, which may cause some confusion.

Comment: hi Brosef. Here is helpful code for recorder => https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`directoryURL` is proper, yet it appears mistaken for `recordingURL`. The `recordSettings` are coherent as well. Let me offer a working version.

### Swift 3

```
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!

let recordSettings = [
    AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value:Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(1)),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey :
        NSNumber(value: Int32(AVAudioQuality.medium.rawValue))]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: directoryURL()!,
                                            settings: recordSettings)
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {}
}

func directoryURL() -> URL? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as URL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
    return soundURL
}

@IBAction func doRecordAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioRecorder.isRecording {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            audioRecorder.record()
        } catch {}
    }
}

@IBAction func doStopAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
    } catch {}
}
```

**Legacy: Swift 2**

```
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!

let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey :
        NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue))]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.directoryURL()!,
            settings: recordSettings)
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {}
}

func directoryURL() -> NSURL? {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,
                                            inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
    return soundURL 
}

@IBAction func doRecordAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioRecorder.recording {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            audioRecorder.record()
        } catch {}
    }
}

@IBAction func doStopAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
    } catch {}
}
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32342486) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32342486).

Comment: I do have most of that code included, but I skipped it since it doesn't really play a part in the error that is being displayed.  I'll edit it in though.

Comment: Thanks!  I removed the inline error parameter and left it as `audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: recordingURL!, settings: recordSettings)` and placed it in a do/catch.  That error description was really unclear.