# NSData from MPMediaItem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can anyone please help me how to convert a song selected from Media library of device into NSData?
I need a function which accept a Media item and returns NSData for that particular media item.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```
MPMediaItem *item = // obtain the media item
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// Get raw PCM data from the track
NSURL *assetURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

const uint32_t sampleRate = 16000; // 16k sample/sec
const uint16_t bitDepth = 16; // 16 bit/sample/channel
const uint16_t channels = 2; // 2 channel/sample (stereo)

NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary dictionary];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:assetURL options:opts];
AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:NULL];
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sampleRate], AVSampleRateKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt:bitDepth], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey, nil];

AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:        [[asset tracks] objectAtIndex:0] outputSettings:settings];
[asset release];
[reader addOutput:output];
[reader startReading];

// read the samples from the asset and append them subsequently
while ([reader status] != AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted) {
CMSampleBufferRef buffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
if (buffer == NULL) continue;

CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(buffer);
size_t size = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBuffer);
uint8_t *outBytes = malloc(size);
CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBuffer, 0, size, outBytes);
CMSampleBufferInvalidate(buffer);
CFRelease(buffer);
[data appendBytes:outBytes length:size];
free(outBytes);
```

Comment: Hi I tried using this; are you sure the data we get back is right? I tried to compress it with zlib and it didnt do a good job. And btw where does whe `while` loop end?  Thank you