# ios load audio file from local storage in swift 3

Tags: ios, upload, nsdata

I have File path And i want to load that file and convect into nsdata and upload on server so please give code that pick up file and convert in nsdata which Alamofire will accept.

Comment: try something then ask question if you face any issue

Comment: I try this code                                                                                                 let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

Comment: You should post you code snippets that you have tried, So people can help you more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you have file path then use this code to convert file into `NSData`.

**Objective-C :**

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
if (fileData) {  
    // do something useful  
}
```

**Swift :**

```
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath)
if (fileData) 
    // do something useful
}
```

Comment: i want to load file from local storage of iphone.

Comment: but i want load that file and than convert into nsdata and upload on server

Comment: where is your file located (in main bundle or in document directory) ?

Comment: ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=7779908289135503347) this is file location

Comment: please see this similar question for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824983/nsdata-from-mpmediaitem