# Decompress gzip compressed file on iOS (using Objective-Zip or SSZipArchive)

Tags: ios, zip, gzip, ssziparchive, objectivezip

I am looking for an easy way to decompress a gzip-compressed file on iOS. I found the libs "SSZipArchive" and "Objective-Zip" but I can't get neither to work.

My impression is that both try to handle my file as a zip archive and therefore fail to handle my `gz` file. (How can I prove my assumption to be true?)

Do I have to use other methods to tell either one that I have a gzip compressed file?

Comment: For a GZip you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Use zlib.  It's already part of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the NSData category from @BradLarson [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234099/332248).